# context.getImageData().data returning 0 for pixels past a certain point

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am using getImageData() to retrieve the pixel data of .jpg images. The function works perfectly for small images but doesn't on larger images (say around 240x240 and up). With larger images it ends up just returning 0 for all pixels beyond a certain point.

The image gets drawn perfectly and my use cases fall within the limits mentioned elsewhere with widths and heights in the tens of thousands being allowed.

```
function showImage(fileReader) {
    var img = document.getElementById("myImage");  
    img.onload = () => getImageData(img);
    img.src = fileReader.result; 
}

function getImageData(img) {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    let imageArr = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height).data;
    imageHeight = img.height;
    imageWidth = img.width;

    console.log(imageArr);
```

I can't seem to find any other posts with this exact issue. I get no console errors.

Is there something wrong with what I am doing and how can I get past this ?

Comment: This could be due to the image being bigger than the canvas. That function reads the canvas data. If your canvas isn’t at least as big as the picture that is one reason you could be having the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just forgot to set the canvas width/height to the same size as the image before drawing the image to the canvas...

```js
ctx.canvas.width = img.width
ctx.canvas.height = img.height
ctx.getImageData(...
```

---

Anyway here is a modern approach that uses OffscreenCanvas + createImageBitmap
(this makes it possible to run it in web workers)

```js
/**
 * @param {ImageBitmap} bitmap
 */
function getClampedArr (bitmap) {
  // Set the canvas to be the same size as the image
  const ctx = new OffscreenCanvas(bitmap.width, bitmap.height).getContext('2d')
  ctx.drawImage(bitmap, 0, 0)
  return ctx.getImageData(0, 0, bitmap.width, bitmap.height).data
}

// Simulate a file u would normaly get from a file input
const url = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="
fetch(url).then(r => r.blob()).then(file => 
    
  // This is what you want to do with your file
  createImageBitmap(file)
    .then(getClampedArr)
  
).then(console.log, console.error)
```